# Using keyboard with Adobe Air and Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

When executing the app as a swf it works fine. When running it using the exe file AIR generates, it doesn't get the keyboard input.

I tried both of this:

```
StarlingStartup.mStarling.nativeStage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
```

and

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
```

Without any luck.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but did you make sure you import the `starling.events.KeyboardEvent` and not the native one, `flash.events.KeyboardEvent`?

Comment: Hi Atriace. Yep, I did that. Also tried the flash version when using nativestage.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I was using `stageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN` instead of `stageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`

It seems that was preventing AIR from getting keyboard input